# How do you change view controllers using code only, explained?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I don't understand how to change to a different view controller using code only in xcode. Please show me how, explain what variables and where I use it please.

EDIT:
I tried this, but the simulator just stops with no errors.

Control drag from the yellow button of the originating view to the next view, and set the identifier as toblack.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toblack" sender:self];
```

but it just stops, saying thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 and highlighted in green

Comment: That completely depends on what you are using in your app. Are you using a `UINavigationController` or just a single `UIVIewController` where you want to present a second one?

Comment: I'm using UIViewController, and I'm trying to use segues but my program crashes with no errors but a breakpoint

Comment: @user261686 please post your code and the error you are getting, this will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Transitioning between view controller is usually done either `modally` or through the use of a `navigation controller`.

If done modally:

```
//Show a new view controller
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:animated completion:^{
    //Completion block
}];

//Dismiss a view controller
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:^{
    //Completion block
}];
```

If done through a navigation controller:

```
//Show a new view controlller
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];

//Go back
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
```

Comment: what's completion? I'm really noobish at this sorry

Comment: If you want to execute a block of code after the view is shown/hidden. If not, then set it to `nil` instead of `^{}`

Comment: I'm trying to do it modally, I don't really get it. Where do i place the name of the next view controller?

Comment: Well try understanding the code. `self` = current view controller. So you can translate that into `Current view controller present me another view controller, animated, when completed, perform this`.